# Visual Studio creates empty TargetFrameworkProfile in csproj when changing .NET versions

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. When I change the .NET Framework version of a project, either upgrading or downgrading, Visual Studio automatically creates this in the XML of the `csproj` file:

```xml
<TargetFrameworkProfile />
```

What does this mean? Does it do anything? If I erase it, the project still runs fine as far as I can tell. Why does Visual Studio create this?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, I'm upgrading .Net framework version from 4.6.1 to 4.8 and empty <TargetFrameworkProfile /> is adding in .csproj file. If remove this from .csproj, Is this impact anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This setting is only applies to portable class libraries (Cross-platform).

Portable class libraries - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/framework/cross-platform/portable-class-library

Comment: Thanks, but that page does not contain the text `TargetFrameworkProfile` on it, so I'm not sure that this is a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you can find here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-target-framework-and-target-platform?view=vs-2022

A target profile is a subset of a target framework. For example, the .NET Framework 4 Client profile does not include references to the MSBuild assemblies.

And here you can find more info about profiles in .NET: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html